# How to get "Policy: X509v3 Any Policy" in a certificate generated with OpenSSL?

Tags: certificates, public-key-infrastructure, openssl, x.509

I am trying to generate a certificate through OpenSSL which has the following line

```
X509v3 Certificate Policies: 
    Policy: X509v3 Any Policy
```

But I end up getting

```
X509v3 Certificate Policies:
    Policy: itu-t
```

What change do I need in my `openssl.cnf` to get "X509v3 Any Policy"?

I don't see any itu-t reference in my cnf file - so I don't know where that is coming from?

Comment: 'itu-t' is the decoding of a zero "OID" (in quotes, because an OID isn't valid without at least two arcs). Apparently you did something wrong. Two approaches:

**What actually is in your cert?** Run `openssl asn1parse <cert.pem` and five lines after the end of your subject name you should have 'cont[3]' then SEQUENCE then one or more SEQUENCE of OBJECT (meaning OID) and OCTET STRING. Find the OCTET STRING just after OBJECT : X509v3 Certificate Policies. Take the number at the left of that line and redo asn1parse adding `-strparse $num`. ...

Comment: ... The other approach is **how did you create this cert**? Give details. Hint: If I just configure certificatePolicies=anyPolicy in the exts section selected by the subcommand and options I use, it works as expected.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 - how did I create what cert?

Comment: The one where you 'end up getting' 'itu-t' which you say is not what you want. To expand, there are at least 5 different ways of creating a cert with openssl commandline, and how you add extensions like the one you ask about depends on which of these ways you are using.

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a more elegant way to do it, but I add the following option to the `[ v3_ca ]` section of my OpenSSL configuration file:

```
certificatePolicies = 2.5.29.32.0
```

The OID values are available at http://www.alvestrand.no/objectid/2.5.29.32.0.html .